# How to exit a function because a key was pressed?

Tags: python

Im trying to move my Cursor every three seconds and if it went too far, reset it to its original location. I want the program to stop after I press any key on the keyboard.

It doesnt seem to work though... what could I be missing? This is what I came up with:

```
import win32api, win32con, time, sys, msvcrt

global z
z=10

def kbfunc():
    #this is boolean for whether the keyboard has bene hit
    x = msvcrt.kbhit()
    if x:
        sys.exit
    else:
        ret = False
    return ret

def move(x,y):
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, int(x/1920*65535.0), int(y/1080*65535.0))

while True:
    move(960,540+z)
    time.sleep(3)
    if z>100:
        move(960,540)
        z += -100
    z + 10
    kbfunc()
```

Comment: The statement `sys.exit` does absolutely nothing - you've merely mentioned the name of a function, not actually called it.  Try `sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying around with the given answers, the finished solution looks like this:

```
global z
z=10

def move():
    mouse.move(10, 10, absolute=False, duration=1)

def moveback():
    mouse.move(-10, -10, absolute=False, duration=1)

while True:
    move()
    time.sleep(3)
    moveback()
    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed
        break  # finishing the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install the keyboard module:

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

And than add it to your loop:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    move(960,540+z)
    time.sleep(3)

    if z>100:
        move(960,540)
        z += -100
    z + 10

    if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break  # finishing the loop
```

Comment: Thx - works and makes de kbfunc being redundant, but the movement sems to be stuck on the original coordinates

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that `msvcrt.kbhit()` does not store previous hits. It only tells you if a key is hit at the current moment in time. You can loop checking for keyboard hits. If no hits before 3 seconds, return:

```
import time
import msvcrt
import sys

def kbfunc(max_time=3):
    start = time.time()
    while not msvcrt.kbhit():
        end = time.time()
        if end - start >= max_time:
            break
    else:
        sys.exit()
```